# Android Multiple Buttons with different Actions

Tags: android

I create buttons dynamically based on the size of an array list that i get from another object. For each entry of the arraylist i need to create three buttons each one with different action.

Like this i need to create 3 times the sizes of arraylist number of buttons. If i had only one set of buttons I can write `onClick()`-method which takes the id of the button but here i have 3 buttons for each entry and need to write 3 different actions for those three buttons.

How could this be done?

Comment: i think you can use the method setTag() to give each one of the three buttons a tag , and then you can know which button is clicked and define his action ,

Answer (score 1):

Similar thing I have done when i needed a textview for each of my array item.it was like-

```
String[] arrayName={"abc","def","ghi"};
for(int i=0;i<arrayName.length;i++)     
    {
        TextView tv=new TextView(context);
        tv.setPadding(20, 5, 40, 5);                
        tv.setText(arrayName[i]);
        tv.setTextSize(1, 12);

        tv.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        tv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#2554C7"));
        tv.setClickable(true);
        tv.setId(i);            

        layout.addView(tv);         
    }
```

In same way,you can add button in similar way. and in click event of each of them,you can code for their actions separately.(I have not tried this).So in each iteration,you will have 3 buttons for each of the array item.

**Edit - 1:**

You can differentiate ids like:

```
mButton1.setId(Integer.parseInt(i+"1"));  
mButton2.setId(Integer.parseInt(i+"2"));
mButton3.setId(Integer.parseInt(i+"3"));
```

Then you can set click listener on each of the button like mButton1.setOnClickListener... and so on.

Comment: if he sets the id alone , the three buttons will have the same id , so he can't specify which button will execute the action , so in this case , he can use the method setTag() ; and on the method onClick() he can differenciate the buttons by getting Tags : getTag();

Comment: now that -'s good , you understand it , it's the same solution as setTag() :) +1

Answer (score 0):

Declare a list of buttons:

```
private List<Button> buttons = new ArrayList<Button>();
```

Then add each button to this list:

```
buttons.add(0, (Button) findViewById(id in ur layout));
```

Inside a for loop give click listener:

```
Button element = buttons.get(i);
element.setOnClickListener(dc);
```

where dc is ur object name for your inner class that implements OnClickListener.

To access each button you can give:

```
Button myBtn;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    myBtn = (Button) v;
        // do operations related to the button
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create the Common Listener class for your button action event and set the used into the `setOnClickListener()` method

Now set the unique id for the buttons.

Now suppose your class look like this :

```
class MyAction implements onClickListener{
     public void onClick(View view){
          // get the id from this view and set into the if...else or in switch 
          int id = view.getId();
          switch(id){
               case 1:
               case 2:
               /// and so on...
          }
          //// do operation here ...
     }
}
```

set this listener in button like this way.

```
Button b1 = new Button(context);
b1.setId(1);
b1.setOnClickListenr(new MyAction());
Button b2 = new Button(context); 
b2.setId(2);
b2.setOnClickListener(new MyAction());
```